# Show that scatter matrix is possitive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance, positive-definite

If we have a sample with size $n$ $(\mathbf x_1,\dots, \mathbf x_n)$, where $\mathbf x_j \in \mathbb R^p$, the scatter matrix is defined as
$$ S=\sum _{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf {x} _{j}-{\overline {\mathbf {x} }})(\mathbf {x} _{j}-{\overline {\mathbf {x} }})^{T},$$
where $\overline{\mathbf {x}}={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{j=1}^{n}\mathbf {x} _{j}$ is sample mean. I found on [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices#The_trace_of_a_1_.C3.97_1_matrix) that:

> $S$ is positive definite if there exists a subset of the data consisting of $p$ linearly independent observations...

but I don't know how to show that (I can show only that it is positive semi-definite).

Comment: It is the differences $\mathbf x_j - \bar {\mathbf x}$ that must be linearly independent. $\qquad$

Comment: Affine independence rather than linear independence is what is needed here, and I have edited the Wikipedia article accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Tnx for correction. Do you know how can I use affine independence to show that matrix is positive definite?

Comment: I'll be back later and will probably post an answer if no on else posts the same answer first. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy There is still no answer after one week. Can you post an answer or suggest some steps in proof?